# Is there any alternative for date_parse function for php 5.1.*?

Tags: php

I have to use php function date_parse but it is supported for 5.2.*. So is there any alternative for function date_parse for php 5.1.*.

Comment: Um... What do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you musicfreak. After viewing your comment solution came on my mind what i need to do. I just wanted to get month day and year separately from the date format (2009-05-21). I used explode("-","2009-05-21",3).....

Answer (score 6):

[strtotime](http://au.php.net/strtotime), possibly combined with [getdate](http://au.php.net/getdate), [localtime](http://au.php.net/localtime) or [gmtime](http://au.php.net/gmtime)

```
getdate(strtotime("20 Jan 2009"));
```

strtotime takes a string, and converts it into a unix timestamp, and the other three functions convert a unix timestamp into an array like date_parse.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
getdate(strtotime($datestr))
```

Note that some keys are slightly different (eg. 'seconds' rather than 'second' and 'mday' rather than 'day') and getdate doesn't include any error information.  `getdate` also doesn't support fractions of a second.

Comment: Ah - yeah, what you said. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean by alternative but check this out:

[php.net getdate()](http://php.benscom.com/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

*Tip:  look to the left you will see related functions.*

Answer (score 0):

Just wonder what for?

strtotime() seems to be the closest answer. Use timestamps (see time(), mktime() etc.) to avoid such string parsing.